# How to do a server-side HTTP Redirect updating the referrer (changing the original one)

Tags: javascript, http, redirect, referrer

I need to do a server-side redirect (HTTP 301, 302, or whatever server-side way to do it) but **updating the referrer (changing the original one)**.

Given this scenario: `siteA -> siteB (which redirects to siteC) -> siteC`

It seems that the regular behavior in all browsers is to keep the original referer, so `siteC` will read a referrer of `siteA`. But I need to update that referrer, so that `siteC` reads a referrer of `siteB` instead of `siteA`.

Is that possible?

Currently I'm using client-side Javascript code:
`window.location.href = "http://siteC";`. But of course that's very far from perfect for various reasons. How can I improve this situation?

Answer (score 0):

For security reasons you can **NOT** change the referrer. Browser's won't allow you.